# How can I partition a singly linked list around a value, using two seperate functions in main() - one lesserThan and the other greaterThan - in C/C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I have the following linked list:
2->1->9->8->3->1->nullptr.

I want to partition the linked list around the value 4, such that all values less than 4, come before all values greater than or equal to 4.

I can partition the linked list using a single function. But, I want to do it using two function - a function  `lesserThan(head,x)` and a function `greaterThan(head, x)` - where x is the value around which I want to partition the list.

But, I am running into the following problem: If I use both functions together, the list nodes are modified by the first function - and, the second function works on that modified nodes. The functions work fine, when the other one is commented out. That is, `lesserThan(head,x)` works fine, when `greaterThan(head, x)` is commented out, and vice-versa.

How can I partition the linked list, by still using both the functions in main()? The main problem I am having is that the nodes are getting modified in both lesserThan and greaterThan functions, and that is getting reflected in main().

Following is the code:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    return temp;
}

Node* lesserThan(Node* head, int x)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node* list1=nullptr, *temp1 = nullptr;

    if ((head)->data < x)
    {
        temp1=list1 = head;
    }
    else
    {
        while (head && head->data >= x)
        {
            head = head->next;
        }
        if (head && head->data < x)
        {
            temp1 = list1 = head;
        }
    }

    Node* curr = temp1;
    if(curr) 
        curr = curr->next;
    while (curr)
    {
        Node* next = curr->next;
        if (curr->data<x)
        {
            list1->next = curr;
            list1 = curr;
            list1->next = nullptr;
        }
        curr = next;
    }
    return temp1;
}

Node* greaterThan(Node* head, int x)
{
    Node* temp2 = nullptr, *list2=nullptr;

    if (head->data >= x)
    {
        temp2 =list2= head;
    }
    else
    {
        while (head && head->data < x)
        {
            head = head->next;
        }
        if (head && head->data >= x)
        {
            temp2 = list2 = head;
        }
    }

    Node* curr = list2;
    if (curr)
        curr = curr->next;
    while (curr)
    {
        Node* next = curr->next;
        if (curr->data >= x)
        {
            list2->next = curr;
            list2 = curr;
            list2->next = nullptr;
        }
        curr = next;
    }
    return temp2;
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = newNode(2);
    head->next = newNode(1);
    head->next->next = newNode(9);
    head->next->next->next = newNode(8);
    head->next->next->next->next = newNode(3);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(1);
    int x = 4;

    Node* p1 = lesserThan(head,x);
    Node* p2 = greaterThan(head, x);
    if (p1 != nullptr)
        p1->next = p2;

    while (p1)
    {
        cout << p1->data << " ";
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Following are the two functions, that fail to work together, because the List nodes are modified by the first function (and second function), and that is reflected in main() -

[image: Two functions effecting each other in main()]

How can I have the two functions in main, so that they don't effect each other? I tried creating different variables for head, and passing them to the functions. But that didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make a second copy of the original list. And select one language tag.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, is there any other way that I can do this, without making a copy of the original list?

Comment: Unrelated: Make a smarter constructor (or `newNode` function- which should be a constructor) that allows you to set the `next` pointer and the whole `Node* head = newNode(2);
    head->next = newNode(1);
    head->next->next = newNode(9);
    head->next->next->next = newNode(8);
    head->next->next->next->next = newNode(3);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(1);` blob gets a lot easier to write: `Node* head = newNode(2,newNode(1, newNode(9, newNode(8, newNode(3, )newNode(1)))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to use insert recursive function instead of your style and note that you have undeleted allocated nodes. I didn't consider them. Any way, I think the following code works as intented

```
struct Node
{
    Node() = default;
    Node( int dataVal ):data{dataVal}{}
    int data{};
    Node* next{};
};

Node*& lessThan( Node* const & head, int x){

        if( !head ) throw std::invalid_argument("Empty linked list");

        Node* toBeReturned;
        Node*  currentHeadNode = head;
        Node**  currentReturned = & toBeReturned;

        while( currentHeadNode ){

            if(currentHeadNode -> data < x ){

                *currentReturned = new Node{ currentHeadNode -> data };
                currentReturned = &((*currentReturned) -> next);
            }

            currentHeadNode = currentHeadNode->next;
        }

        return toBeReturned;
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = new Node(2);
    head->next = new Node(1);
    head->next->next = new Node(9);
    head->next->next->next = new Node(8);
    head->next->next->next->next = new Node(3);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = new Node(1);
    int x = 4;

    Node* p1 = lessThan(head,x);

    while (p1)
    {
        std::cout << p1->data << " ";
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```